# Instance of class created within parameter list of calling method?

Tags: c#, oop

I'm having problems getting an instance of a class to a function, without initializing it beforehand (the way this library has been set up, when creating the class instance, events are triggered, which I do not want to happen initially).

```
TopClass TC = new TopClass();
```

and a member of TC (dostuff) can be accessed from class AClass...

```
AClass myClass = TC.dostuff(parameters);
```

a method is defined as:

```
public void MyMethod(Aclass myClass, bool value) {/* */}
```

and the calling method as

```
bool val = true; //or false, depending on what I need

MyMethod(AClass myclass = TC.dostuff(parameters), val);   // Is this really bad?
```

I can't initialize it within MyMethod without triggering the events, and I can't pass a class instance as null, which leaves me with the above. At least this way I can either stop or start the desired events inside MyMethod, depending on the bool value. What is really going on here? (apart from probably not being good OOP design). Would creating a reference to AClass be helpful in such a scenario?

Comment: "Is this really bad?" Well, it won't compile...

Comment: I'm thinking you'll need to be a *lot* more specific here.  Can you show the events? And the *actual* class names...it sounds like your objects are doing way too much in their constructors.

Comment: I don't understand the requirements. What constructor/method triggers events exactly? What is that last line of code? It can't compile. Is that the real problem?

Comment: You're overcomplicating this, just do what BWHazel has suggested.

Comment: The weird thing is that it does compile. I deleted the generated files and rebuilt, with the same result (VS 2013). I'm using the libraries provided by IrrKlang, for sound manipulation. I'm a beginner really, and like some others also have question marks as to how to pass around an instance of their ISound class. Creating an instance triggers the sound itself: e.g. ISound music = engine.Play3D(filenamepath).

Comment: Whether it compiles or not, why are you trying to do it?

Comment: It's the only way I can figure out to have an instance inside the method, which I can then put a stop to immediately i.e. music.Stop() without the music being re-triggered momentarily. If I create the class instance ISound music = engine.Play3D(filenamepath) inside the method (if bool is true), that's fine, but if bool is false then I have to create the instance again, before I can stop it... I know I'm missing a lot of coding knowledge, which is why I' m here! (and I really appreciate the help I'm getting on this site)

Comment: What is the problem of having to call `Play` to get your instance of `ISound`? What would you want to do with it, besides stoping the playing?

Comment: @Patrice Gahide - I suppose it seems wasteful to call it again somehow. I'm imagining that having a free floating instance of ISound without it instantiating anything again just before stopping it, seems neater.  To those who have been patient with me on this thread, in fact I was passing  myclass = TC.dostuff(parameters), as a parameter, without the class name before it - it was a typo on my part here

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `AClass myClass =` from the `MyMethod` call.

```
MyMethod(TC.dostuff(parameters), val);
```

This does not affect the events triggering but will get the `AClass` instance into the method call.

Comment: thank you BWHazel - it was in fact a typo on my part (I hadn't put the class name in). Generally, am interested as to whether it's bad practice or not to pass things this way in a method parameter

Comment: Hi @Chaz - no it's not frowned upon to pass in instances like this; after all it's supported in the language!  However, if the code starts to look unreadable, unmanageable or difficult to understand then it would be better to get the instance first as a named object then pass that in instead.  :)